Do we need not need truth values to describe models in predicate logic?
I am reading Kirby's Model theory. In section 3.3, the following definition of interpretation is given:

$\textbf{Definition 3.4 (Interpretation of formulas)}$ Let $\varphi$ be a formula of $L$ and $\bar{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ a list of variables containing every free variable of $\varphi$. We also write $\varphi(\bar{x})$ for the formula with the list of variables. Let $A$ be an $L$-structure and $\bar{a} = (a_1, \dots, a_n)$ a list of elements of (the domain of) $A$. We define the notion $A \models \varphi(\bar{a})$, read ''$A$ models $\phi(\bar{a})$ or $\varphi(\bar{a})$ is true in $A$'' or $A$ satisfies $\varphi(\bar{a})$ by recursion on formulas. ... (Recursion recipe follows)

In this definition there is no mention of substituting truth values like in propositional logic where we describe models by substitution of truth values for the propositions..  Are models here at all related to models in propositional logic or are they all completely logically independent?

Truth values 'emerge' into the logic using the recursion recipe (presumably part of Def 3.4) applied to atomic formulae.
That is, a well formed $L$-formula $\phi$ is assigned a truth value if $\phi \equiv (t_1 = t_2)$ or $\phi \equiv R(t_1, ..., t_n)$, for some $L$-terms and n-ary relation $R$ in $L$'s signature (under a given $L$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ and assignment $\sigma$ of variables). In particular, $\mathcal{M} \models_\sigma \phi$ is assigned the truth value - in model theory, only interpreted formulas directly recieve truth values. (This leads to the notion of a valid formula, i.e. true under all structures and all assignments.)
Truth values then radiate out to the rest of the language via atomic formulae and the recursion recipe.

There is a relation.
The clauses specifying how to interpret formulas with connectives are the same of propositional logic.
What is specific of predicate logic are those for atomic formulas and quantifiers.
See First-Order Logic: Semantics.
Predicate logic is based on a finer analysis of statements wrt that provided by propositional calculus.
Not only propositions and connectives but now propositions are decomposed into names-properties/relations.

Well, you implicitly do. As the text says:  $A \vDash \phi(a)$ can be read as "$\phi(a)$ is True in model $A$"
So when semantics for operators like $\land$ states that $A \vDash \phi \land \psi$ if and only if $A \vDash \phi$ and $A \vDash \psi$, then that can obviously be understood as $\phi \land \psi$ is true (in $A$) if and only if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both true (in $A$). So it really does follow the same semantics as propositional logic.
